# @PreserveOnRefresh unable to load dynamic Images with StreamResource

Tags: java, vaadin14

I am using vaadin 14 to develop a web page. I have used @PreserveOnRefresh, so that my ui won't change upon refresh. I am able to achieve it, but am losing the images. On first attempt I am able to load the image, but after refresh the images are lost. I have created the image via StreamResource. Can anybody please help me with this usecase? The following is my code snippet:

```
@Route("home")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class HomePage extends VerticalLayout {

    public HomePage(HorizontalLayout base) {
        Div logoContainer = new Div();
        logoContainer.setSizeFull();
        StreamResource streamResource =  new StreamResource("logo", () -> {
            
                        File imgrsc = new File(filepath-to-my-image);
            FileInputStream stream = null;
            try {
                stream = new FileInputStream(imgrsc);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        });
        
        Image image = new Image(streamResource, "");
        logoContainer.add(image);
                base.add(logoContainer);
    }

}
```

I am expecting for my image to be loaded after refresh button/F5 is clicked